# Find all $a,b,c \in \Bbb Z$, such that $a^2 +31b^7=c^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z},$ such that $a^2 +31b^7=c^2.$
Here is my approach:
Factoring $c^2-a^2=31b^7$ we get, $(c+a)(c-a)=31b^7$
$c-a=b^7$
$b=1$

$c+a=31$
$2c=32$
$c=16$
$a=15$

$c-a=31$
$c+a=b^7$

$2c= b^7+31$
$c=(b^7+31)/2$
$a=b^7-31/2$

$b^7=2n-1$
$b=2n-1$

$(15,1,16)((b^7-31)/2,b,(b^7+31)/2) (b=2n-1)$

Is my solution true?

Comment: Have you noted the obvious solution already?

Comment: $$31b^7=c^2-a^2=(c-a)(c+a)$$

Comment: Yes,I have noticed ,but I didn't get the solution.So,please provide me solution.

Comment: Taking individ's approach, let $c-a=1$. Can you proceed?

Comment: Factoring $c^2-a^2=31b^7$ we get, $(c+a)(c-a)=31b^7$
$c-a=b^7$
$b=1$

$c+a=31$
$2c=32$
$c=16$
$a=15$

$c-a=31$
$c+a=b^7$

$2c= b^7+31$
$c=(b^7+31)/2$
$a=b^7-31/2$

$b^7=2n-1$
$b=2n-1$

$(15,1,16)((b^7-31)/2,b,(b^7+31)/2) (b=2n-1)$

Comment: Would you enlighten me how to be gotten the following points:
$b=1$
$b^7=2n-1$
$b=2n-1?$
Thank You!

Comment: Vulch, if you edit the question by pasting your last comment into it, (and formatting it so I can follow what you are saying) it will probably be reopened.

Comment: @abiessu,would you post full solution?Thank You!

Comment: This is still unreadable: please add arrows between steps on the same line. For instance, $a = b \implies c = d$ using \implies.

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b,c\in\Bbb{Z}$ are such that $a^2+31b^7=c^2$ then also
$$31b^7=c^2-a^2=(c+a)(c-a).$$
This yields a factorization $31b^7=uv$, with $u=c+a$ and $v=c-a$, such that
$u\equiv v\pmod{2}$.

Conversely, let $b$ be any integer and $31b^7=uv$ a factorization such that $u\equiv v\pmod{2}$.  Then
$$a:=\frac{u-v}{2}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad c:=\frac{u+v}{2},$$
are integers satisfying  $a^2+31b^7=c^2$.

Comment: I got lost trying to be too specific, thanks for posting a clearer answer.